# Error importing tables in Python in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: python, pandas, pytables

I'm trying to use the HDFStore command in Pandas and although I have PyTables installed, when I run the command:

```
import pandas as pan
filename=('testfile.h5')
store=pan.HDFStore(filename)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dashamstyr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 390, in __init__
    raise ImportError('HDFStore requires PyTables, "{ex}" problem importing'.format(ex=str(ex)))
ImportError: HDFStore requires PyTables, "cannot import name blosc_get_complib_info_" problem importing
```

And when I run the command:

```
import tables
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dashamstyr\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tables\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from tables.utilsextension import (
ImportError: cannot import name blosc_get_complib_info_
```

I using the Anaconda Python distribution for windows 7 64-bit.  I have the following versions of relevant packages (I think they're all up to date):

- Python 2.7.9
- PyTables 3.2.0
- HDF5 1.8.15.1
- Cython 0.22.1
- numexpr 2.4.3
- Pandas 0.16.2

Comment: Are you using conda?  Looks like you might need to update some of pytables dependencies.  Conda should do it automatically but if you didn't use conda you may need to do it manually.  FYI, blosc relates to the compression used by pytables.

Comment: I am using conda.  and have the latest versions of HDF5, Cython, numpy, and numexpr (as far as I know).  The preprequisites for PyTables includes a reference to "c-blosc", but they say it's bundled with PyTables.  I tried to install it manually through conda, but it couldn't find the package.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what could be going on.  Having duplicate python installations is sometimes a problem, so you might double check that (and uninstall as necessary).  You might also try asking here:  https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/anaconda